# MultiBinding on a WPF Listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox, multibinding

How can i use code like this on a listbox???:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>    
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} + {1}">
            <Binding Path="Name" />
            <Binding Path="ID" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

I want to do the above on a listbox. My datasource has two items, forenames and surname and i want to display both. i tried this but its not working:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="listBox" Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="selectionChanged" >
                <ListBox.DisplayMemberPath>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} + {1}">
                        <Binding Path="forenames" />
                        <Binding Path="surname" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </ListBox.DisplayMemberPath>
            </ListBox>
```

Please note i want to use xaml like above and not a separate IConverter class or something.

Comment: Always describe "is not working". Full error messages etc.

Comment: will do that in future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `DisplayMemberPath` use custom `ItemTemplate`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="listBox" Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="selectionChanged" >
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
               <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} + {1}">
                  <Binding Path="forenames" />
                  <Binding Path="surname" />
               </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: you just need to use datatemplate as mentioned @dkozl